# AJAX Request from Table Rows to Details

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

This is my first time on here so I'm sorry if I'm not quite up to snuff with all of you.

In the process of learning AJAX so I'm brand new, but need to get a page done for our staff website.

---

I have a page (php) which builds a list through a mysql query of all patients. I have absolutely no problem with this. However, I'm stuck on this part.

When a user clicks a specific row (aka Patient Name), I want it to pull up the details of that patient associated with it in our mysql database on the right-hand side so the page doesn't have to refresh and they aren't directed to any other pages.

I have seen examples like this when it came to customers, like you click the name and a div appears to the right containing email, phone, etc. etc.

Does anyone have any good starting points? I have searched as far as I can, and I'm beginning to think I'm not using the right language when searching for my answer.

Thanks ahead of time... Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery.
First you need to make a web service on your server. The web service will accept a, let's say, POST parameter which will be either patient name or the patient ID. Based on this id/name you will query your MySQL database, fetch all the details and return as json.

On the front end, you can use jQuery.post(). You will need to pass the appropriate URL and the data. In return, you will get JSON data. In the success callback method of jQuery.post/$.post you can create a div on the right and display those data.

If you are going to return the data in json format, you can also just use $.postJSON()

Please make sure to set the appropriate headers in your PHP webservice. These two are probably the most important

```
Content-Type: application/json // if you are gonna return the data in JSON format
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * // to let the browser pass the data to the DOM model. This is to allow CORS (Cross Origin Resouce Sharing)
```

**SAMPLE:**

example.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
if (isset($_POST['patientID'])) {

    $patientID = $_POST['patientID'];
    $data = array();

    // Enter the appropriate details below
    $mysqli = new mysqli("host", "username", "password", "db_name");

    /* check connection */
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno > 0) {
        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $mysqli->connect_error . ']');
    }

    $statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `patients` WHERE `patientID` = ? LIMIT 1");
    $statement->bind_param('i', $patientID);
    $statement->execute();

    // You need to write a variable for each field that you are fetching from the select statement in the correct order
    // For eg., if your select statement was like this:
    // SELECT name, COUNT(*) as count, id, email FROM patients
    // Your bind_result would look like this:
    // $statement->bind_result($name, $count, $id, $email);
    // PS: The variable name doesn't have to be the same as the column name
    $statement->bind_result($id, $name, $email, $phone);
    while ($statement->fetch()) {
        $data["id"] = $id;
        $data["name"] = $name;
        $data["email"] = $email;
        $data["phone"] = $phone;
    }
    $statement->free_result();

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

example.html

```
<a href="" id="123" onclick="return getPatientData(this);">Patient #123</a>
```

example.js

```
function getPatientData(element) {
    var patientID = $(element).attr("id");
    $.post("example.php", {"patientID": patientID}, function (data) {
        // display the data in appropriate div
    }, 'json');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your samples, I found them extremely helpful. And I understand where your going, I made a couple test runs with alerts (just to make sure everything worked up until I did the fetch with example. But as I haven't done this before, I was wondering if you could show me how to format the database query in this case. I'm familiar with regular mysql queries but I am not quite sure how to add the database query to your example.php. And yes, the coding and database column are exactly the same. Again, I appreciate the help...

Comment: I am glad I was able to help you out. I am not sure what you are asking me here though. Do you want me to write the fetchPatientData function for you?

Comment: I know it may seem a little sad, but yes. If you would like, I could pay you for your time. Like I said, I'm not familiar with this and it'd help me a great deal, especially with learning more about these types of requests. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, I will edit the answer and show the function too. Though, you should understand that these are all merely samples to get you started. You will have to make changes and add error handling and error checks according to your requirements. Also, the thing about paying me, I found it very rude, although I am sure you didn't have any wrong intentions. Thanks!

Comment: @Matthew I have updated the answer. Please mark it as accepted if it has answered your question. Thanks

Comment: I have one more question in regards to this (and no, I really didn't mean to offend, I was just a little worried that you might think I was wasting your time...), I am getting a response (and the appropriate one) on my network console, the only issue is there is an error "json.parse unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the json data" right above it, and I have a feeling this is what is keeping it from loading the data onto the page. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks again for the help, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Matthew It seems that your response is not a valid json probably because of some character. I cannot answer this because I am not sure exactly where the problem lies. Also, this is going beyond the scope of this question. I don't mind helping you out outside of stackoverflow but I don't see how I can get in touch with you.

Answer (score 1):

You should do an jquery ajax call on element click

```
        $('.patientClass').on('click', function() { 

           var patientid = $(this).attr('id');
           // attr('id') should be the patients id
           $.ajax({
                url: "getPatientDetailsURL.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    id: patientid
                },
                    success: function(response) {
                      // create div with response details or append parsed json to existing div
                }
            });
        )}
```

And on the backend get the patiend id with (int)$_POST['id']

Also you on the backend you can set the page to respond only to ajax calls like this:

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
//code here
} else {
// not ajax call
}
```