# adding a DELETE link to my table with the js array push()

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, slim, database-table

I would like to incorporate a link in my table for a delete button. This will then - onclick - delete from my db depending on the ID.

I have searched through stack overflow with no prevail. A point in the right direction would be great (links, code suggestions etc etc..).

The HTML:

```
<h5 class="tabletext"><a href="#">View Markers</a></h5>

     <form action="" method="post">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
           <thead>
              <tr>
                <th data-field="id">ID</th>
                <th data-field="type">Type</th>
                <th data-field="area">Area</th>
                <th data-field="area">Weight in lbs</th>
                <th data-field="area">Length in cm</th>
                <th data-field="area">Latitude</th>
                <th data-field="area">Longitude</th>
                <th data-field="area">DELETE</th>                     
              </tr>
           </thead>
         </table>
      </form>
```

The .js:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        url: "rest/rest/api.php/markerss",
        success: showMarkerTable,
        error: showError
        });

function showMarkerTable(responseData) {

        var items = [];
    $.each(responseData.MARKERS, function(key, val){
        items.push("<tr>");
        items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.id+"</td>");
        items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.area+"</td>");
        items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.type+"</td>");
        items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.weight+"</td>");
        items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.length+"</td>");
        items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.lat+"</td>");
        items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.lng+"</td>");

        //The delete button here
        items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.delete+"</td>");
        items.push("</tr>");
    });
    $("<tbody/>", {html: items.join("")}).appendTo("table");

    }

function showError(){
    alert("Sorry, there was a problem!");
}
```

The php using SLIM framework to retrieve the data:

```
function getTable() {
        $sql="select * FROM markers ORDER BY id";

    try{
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $markers = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;

        responseJson('{"MARKERS":'.json_encode($markers).'}',200);
        }

        catch(PDOException $e){
        responseJson('{"error":{"text":'.$e->getMessage().'}}',500);
        }
}
```

Comment: you can attach an event on the delete button & send to api via ajax for deletion

Comment: I don't have the knowledge for that, would you have any tutorial links? @AgamBanga

Comment: This should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28778753/ajax-request-from-table-rows-to-details   Let me know in case you have any issue